# CheckRedirectionStatus is always can not redirect for Safari on

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, safari

I have a provider hosted sharepoint add-in, the part that is failing just deletes a list item from Sharepoint.

The code works perfectly fine for google Chrome, firefox, IE, Edge, and even on MAC, and mobile it works across all browsers.

However with Safari, I always get the normal Add in Error page: Unexpected Error.

I will paste first here the code and then I will explain my findings:

View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteClassified", "Clasificados", new { SPHostUrl = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(HttpContext.Current.Request).AbsoluteUri }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "FormDeleteClasificados" }))
            {
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" id="modalDeleteClasificados">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="left:0; width:90%;height:90%;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h2 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel"><b>Borrar clasificado</b></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <p><b>¿ Esta seguro que desea eliminar este clasificado ?</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="submit" id="Si" style="border-radius: 5px; background: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; color: #FFF; margin: 5px 10%; width:80%; font-size: 14px;" class="btn" name="submitButton" value="SI" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <a style="border-radius: 5px; background: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; color: #FFF; margin: 5px 10%; width:80%; font-size: 14px;" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">NO</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
        }

function ModalBorrar(val)
        {
            $("#modalDeleteClasificados").modal("show");
            document.getElementById("FormDeleteClasificados").action =  "/Clasificados/DeleteClassified?SPHostUrl=@Html.Raw(url)&id="+val;

        }
```

The controller is like this:

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public ActionResult DeleteClassified(int id)
        {
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                    try
                    {
                        List lstClassified = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Clasificados");
                        ListItem oListItem = lstClassified.GetItemById(id);
                        oListItem.DeleteObject();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        string URL = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).AbsoluteUri;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Clasificados", new { SPHostUrl = URL, Mensaje = "Clasificado eliminado correctamente" });
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        string URL = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).AbsoluteUri;
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Clasificados", new { SPHostUrl = URL, Mensaje = "Error al tratar de elminar el clasificado" });
                        throw;
                    }
            }
        }
```

When I put a breakpoint in VS on this method it works across all browsers, however with Safari when debugging I noticed the following:

1. On the ActionExecuting event in the context filter, on the switch statement it returns can not redirect

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
           {
               if (filterContext == null)
               {
                   throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
               }

   ```
           Uri redirectUrl;
           switch (SharePointContextProvider.CheckRedirectionStatus(filterContext.HttpContext, out redirectUrl))
           {
               case RedirectionStatus.Ok:
                   return;
               case RedirectionStatus.ShouldRedirect:
                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl.AbsoluteUri);
                   break;
               case RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect:
                   filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
                   break;
           }
       }
   ```

When checking the method CheckRedirectionStatus on SharepointContext.cs, it fails on this if:

```
if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(httpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "POST"))
            {
                return RedirectionStatus.CanNotRedirect;
            }
```

This is obviosly a POST request, but then why does it work in every single browser except Safari?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?